# Data not retrieving when clicking on search button

Tags: selenium, button, search, frames

The search button is inside the frame and I am connecting to the frame with the below code.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("autoCompleteDialogIF");
```

I am able to go the frames section.

Search button syntax:

```
<a href="javascript:findButtonAction();">Find</a>
```

Here in the frame section I have text box and when I enter the values in text box and perform search the data is not retrieving which matches with the text.

Code used:

```
WebElement elementclick = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='filterPanelFindButton']/a"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elementclick);
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information as: 1. How did you confirm its a frame? 2. How did you confirm you are connecting to the frame, show us your code? 3. Can you please share the relevant HTML DOM?

Answer (score 1):

Try to click on element using `java-script executor` method.

```
WebElement elementclick = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Find')]"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elementclick);
```

> OR

Try to click on element using `xpath` locator with `Explicit wait` method.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Find')]"))));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Find')]")).click();
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as `Accepted` if it's resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Find"))
```